# Which one is correct to place have or not?

Tags: grammar

I want to know which one is correct

I have forwarded the automated emails that I have received from X

Or

I forwarded the automated emails that I received from X

Comment: The first one indirectly means, "That work is (now) done". The second directly means, "I did that work (in the past)".

Comment: so there is no incorrect answer it depends on the time of the action right?

Comment: The time of the action is the same in both cases. The choice depends on whether you want to *tell the story of the past action* itself (simple past), or *give the present result* of a past action (present perfect).

Comment: thank you, another question is it valid to use the same tense before and after "that" ?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, both your sentences above are good.